# 20 dependency to pass through the constructor to do IOC

Tags: architecture

I have a class called MessageService. This class is responsible for receiving  email (flows actually). Depending on the subject of the mail , it detects which flow is at stake and perform an action.

a bit of code to explain my problem might more simple :

```
public class MessageService
{
    public void ReadEmail()
    {
      switch (subject)
         "1" :
          Myservice.action1(); break;
         "2" :
          Myservice.action2(); break;
         "qwwerty" :
          MyOtherservice.Querty(); break;
          etc...
    }
}
```

In order to do some inversion of control  , I wanted to pass the references to the services through the constructor of my class MessageService.

```
public MessageService(IMyService myService,IMyOtherservice myOtherservice, ect....)
{
    Myservice=myService;
    MyOtherservice=myOtherservice;
}
```

It would work great for a few references, but the class MessageService might deal with up to 20,30 or forty flows differents. And this would make the initialisation of my class a bit heavy.

Is there some nicer way to achieve it ? through some design pattern ? Should I care about IOC (though, I like it to run my tests on the class after..)?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want to use the Chain-of-Responsibility design pattern.  Create an interface that knows how to deal with emails and build separate classes for each task you want to do (roughly equivalent to your switch statement (`switch`, btw, is a very naive implementation of COR)).  Those classes will each take only the service they require.  Then in `MessageService` take a list of these interfaces and process them one at a time until one of them indicates it has handled it:

```
public interface IMessageReader
{
  /// <returns><c>true</c> if handled; otherwise false
  bool ReadEmail(Mail message);
}

public class QwertyMessageReader : IMessageReader
{
  public QwertyMessageReader(IMyOtherService otherService) {/*set*/}
  public bool ReadEmail(Mail message)
  {
     if(message.Subject.Equals("qwwerty"))
     {
       otherService.Querty();
       return true;
     }
     return false;
  }
}

public class MessageService
{
    public MessageService(IEnumerable<IMessageReader> readers) {/*set*/}
    public void ReadEmail()
    {
      var handled = readers.Select(reader => reader.ReadEmail(message))
                           .FirstOrDefault(result => result);
    }
}
```

You'll need to tweak the interfaces and code above to fit what you are doing, but this is the major concept.

Most decent IOC containers will automatically generate the IEnumerable<> for you if you register multiple of the same interface.

Comment: Nice solution I like it much. Unfortunately, I am not sure my IOC will do the job because, it somewhat self made by some colleague and people are really reluctant to turn to something different. I'll see what I can do, and I ll be back .. Thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

The best suggestion would be to break your class down into smaller classes.  Having 30 or 40 dependencies in a single class is a sign that it's doing too much.  Try to break each class into something that only does one thing, and then you can start to compose them together into larger bits of functionality.  Since you're using an IoC container, this should actually not be too hard to do, and will make your code easier to test.  The ideal goal would be to shoot for one or two dependencies per class, but realistically, I think 4 or 5 is a good goal to go for at first.

Not knowing exactly what your code is doing, it's hard to suggest specific design patterns.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I am a bit lost as to know how to break my classes... I 'll give a more deep look, and tells you if I find anything.. Thanks all the same.